# indicate a numerical value in the abstract

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

When I learned Pascal lo' these many years ago (circa 1980) it had a loopy sort of pseudo-parser description. I also learned Backus-Naur forms and adopted the  convention using "<" and ">" to enclose values of a particular class. I have not seen much use of either formalism in questions and there is even a hostility, if I may, toward using "<" and ">" since those delimiters have been co-opted by HTML syntax. So what is the preferred method for displaying a value that you want to leave "open" or not-yet-evaluated? (I have searched Meta-SO to see if there is prior work and come up empty. I cannot even find what I consider to be correct tags.)

I do know that the current parsing engine accepts `<` and `>`, and I am under the impression that SO and Meta-SO are akin with respect to this.

Comment: Does this question come down to how to render `<` and `>`?

Comment: I think that I can now do that with backticks, but the fact that it seemed to take some time before that was accepted by the SO parser left me with the feeling that there must be some other formalism in the minds of the site authors. That and the fact that is seldom see that construction.

Comment: If you don't want to use code formatting, you can also render `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`...if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: I was trying to elicit opinion about how to communicate effectively, given that fact that the notation I was using required obscure hoops initially. I wanted to understand if the notational conventions had migrated over the decades.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is add a highlighting override to ensure that the listing doesn't get mistaken for HTML. I typically use lang-none. Here's an example from [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769786/css3s-attr-doesnt-work-in-major-browsers/8769922#8769922):

```
Looking at the grammar that's given in the spec:

<!-- language: lang-none -->

    attr( <attr-name> <type-or-unit>? [ , <fallback> ]? )
```

Comment: That does look like a useful construct. Seems your syntactic description could be `attr( <attr-name> <space> <type-or-unit>? [ , <fallback> ]? )`? You mention the "spec". Can you post a link? My searching in Meta and SO with search terms "SO specification" is pulling up nothing in the first few pages that is on point.

Comment: @BondedDust: That is part of the quote from my original answer, referencing the W3C specification given in the question where the description is taken from, namely http://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#attr-notation Sorry for the confusion.